# Text correction Damereau Levenshtein python

Tags: python, spell-checking, damerau-levenshtein

I want to correct a text by using Damereau Levenshtein python (because it also considers transposition). I need to replace all the words of my input text by the words in a dictionary that have a distance of 1. How can I do this ?

Is there another way to correct automatically spelling mistakes ?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Well, there exists a ready-made [Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.12.0) to solve your problem.
I think the method `distance(string1, string2)` should at least solve half your problem.

Comment: thanks, but this package doesn't consider transposition